# Download a file and pipe to multiple commands

Tags: bash, pipe

I see a lot of installation instructions which ask you to download a file and run it straight away like this: `wget https://some-site.com/some-file.sh | bash`. However I would like to pipe the file through to `less` first so I can see the file before piping the file to `bash`. How can I do this in a one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `vipe` from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).  Demo with `seq 20` instead of `wget`.

Run this:

```
seq 20 | EDITOR=less vipe | wc -l
```

...and `less` opens the pipe for viewing.  Press `q` to *quit* `less`, and the line count from `wc -l` appears:

```
20
```

Now do the same:

```
seq 20 | EDITOR=less vipe | wc -l
```

...but this time, hit *Ctrl-C*, then `q` to *quit* `less`.  Because of the *Ctrl-C*, `wc` never runs.

Therefore this should work:

```
wget -qO- https://some-site.com/some-file.sh | EDITOR=less vipe | bash
```

And if the code doesn't please, hit *Ctrl-C*.

If you want to keep the file around despite *maybe* not wanting to run it, try this:

```
wget -qO- https://some-site.com/some-file.sh | tee /tmp/some-file.sh |
EDITOR=less vipe | bash
```

...and it'll work much the same, except that */tmp/some-file.sh* will have the pipe contents as well.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the file.
2. Look at it.
3. Run it.

```
$ curl -O https://some/url/file.sh
$ less file.sh
$ bash file.sh
```

That would be easiest and most robust.

Answer (score 1):

Within `less`, you can press `s` to save the input to a file.

Or `g` to get to the top and then `|$bash` to pipe to `bash`.